# how to compile and run java file using jsp page and in tomcat 8

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

### alumini.java:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;


public class  alumini extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException{ 
        String aluno=req.getParameter("aluno");
        String fname=req.getParameter("fname");
        String mname=req.getParameter("mname");
        String lname=req.getParameter("lname");
        String passyr=req.getParameter("passyr");
        String dept=req.getParameter("dept");
        String enroll=req.getParameter("enroll");

        String connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"; //connection variable

        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement st = null;
try { 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection
    (connectionURL, "root", ""); 
    String sql = "insert into alumini (aluno,fname,mname,lname,passyr,dept,enroll) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    st = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    st.setString(1, aluno);
    st.setString(2, fname);
    st.setString(3, mname);
    st.setString(4, lname);
    st.setString(5, passyr);
    st.setString(6, dept);
    st.setString(7, enroll);
    st.executeUpdate();
    st.close();
    connection.close();
}catch(Exception E){
    System.out.println("The error is=="+E.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

### alumini.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Alumini Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="alumini" method="get" name="alu">
<table>
<tr><td><label>Alumini Number: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="aluno"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>First Name : </label></td><td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Middle Name: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="mname"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Last Name: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="lname"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Year of Passing: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="passyr"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Department: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="dept"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Enrollment Number: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="enroll"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1"
  metadata-complete="true">

  <display-name>Servlet in Tomcat</display-name>
  <description>
     This is Servlet
  </description>

<servlet> 
<servlet-name>alumini</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>alumini</servlet-class>
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>alumini</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/alumini</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

I compiled java file and class file (alumini.class) is put in classes under WEB-INF in root folder(alumini). Also jsp file (alumini.jsp) is put in root folder as well.

### Problem:

When I give input using the jsp form, nothing is shown. Even the Database is not updated..

Comment: Is there anything in your log?

Comment: there are a few logs....
but I have no idea what to look to give you proper information...

Comment: Might make sense to `tail -f` them in different windows and reload the page

Comment: now it started giving 'HTTP status 404' that resource is not available

Comment: If the class is in the package alumini, as the web.xml indicates, then the alumin.class file should be under `WEB-INF/classes/alumini`.

Comment: actually the class file is in 'WEB-INF/classes' only..
how can we conclude from web.xml that where is class file?

and I have corrected that '<servlet-class>alumini.alumini</servlet-class>' to just '<servlet-class>alumini</servlet-class>'

Is there anything more I have to do...? coz its still the same condition.. nothing is displayed on the page and nothing is updated in database...

Comment: Put your classes in packages. Never in the default package. The try again, and check the tomcat logs. And while you're at it, respect the Java naming conventions: classes start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: so will you please explain me what should I do?
I am new to jsp and xml as well..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.
I just had to put mysql-connector.jar file within the
`WEB-INF/lib` directory.
Eventually this has solved my problem!
everything works fine now.